# How to change specific values of a column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

| Sentiment_Label | Sentiment_Score |
| --- | --- |
| Satisfied | 0.882621 |
| Disappointed | 0.826413 |
| Satisfied | 0.893627 |
| Satisfied | 0.863469 |
| Disappointed | 0.982447 |

I want to subtract the Sentiment Scores of all 'Disappointed' values by 1. This would be the desired output:

| Sentiment_Label | Sentiment_Score |
| --- | --- |
| Satisfied | 0.882621 |
| Disappointed | 0.173587 |
| Satisfied | 0.893627 |
| Satisfied | 0.863469 |
| Disappointed | 0.017553 |

I have tried to use the `groupby()` method to split the values into two different columns but the resulting NaN values made it difficult to perform additional calculations. I also want to keep the columns the same.

**Dataframe**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sentiment_Label': ["Satisfied", "Disappointed", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Disappointed"],
                   'Sentiment_Score': [0.882621, 0.826413, 0.893627, 0.863469, 0.982447],
                  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the following:

```
df.loc[df['Sentiment_Label'] == 'Disappointed', 'Sentiment_Score'] -= 1
```

By applying this, you will get:

| Sentiment_Label | Sentiment_Score |
| --- | --- |
| Satisfied | 0.882621 |
| Disappointed | -0.173587 |
| Satisfied | 0.893627 |
| Satisfied | 0.863469 |
| Disappointed | -0.017553 |

Answer (score 1):

You can also use np.where function which works exactly similar to MS-Excel's if function.

```
import numpy as np
( df['Sentiment_Score']= 
np.where(df.Sentiment_Label='Disappointed',df['Sentiment_Score']-1,
df['Sentiment_Score']
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply()` on each row and **define a function** that does `1 - Sentiment_Score` if `Sentiment_Label` value is `Disappointed`:

```
# Function to apply to each row of dataframe
def sub_1(x):
    if x['Sentiment_Label'] == 'Disappointed':
        x["Sentiment_Score"] = 1-x["Sentiment_Score"]
    return x

# Dataframe definition
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sentiment_Label': ["Satisfied", "Disappointed", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Disappointed"],
    'Sentiment_Score': [0.882621, 0.826413, 0.893627, 0.863469, 0.982447],
})

# Apply function to dataframe by rows 
df = df.apply(sub_1, axis=1)
```

`df` value after `apply()`:

```
  Sentiment_Label  Sentiment_Score
0       Satisfied         0.882621
1    Disappointed         0.173587
2       Satisfied         0.893627
3       Satisfied         0.863469
4    Disappointed         0.017553
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`rsub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html):

```
m = df['Sentiment_Label'].eq('Disappointed')
df.loc[m, 'Sentiment_Score'] = df['Sentiment_Score'].rsub(1)
```

Output:

```
  Sentiment_Label  Sentiment_Score
0       Satisfied         0.882621
1    Disappointed         0.173587
2       Satisfied         0.893627
3       Satisfied         0.863469
4    Disappointed         0.017553
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.update( df[df.iloc[:,0].eq("Disappointed")].iloc[:,1].sub(1).abs() )

print(df)
```

```
  Sentiment_Label  Sentiment_Score
0       Satisfied         0.882621
1    Disappointed         0.173587
2       Satisfied         0.893627
3       Satisfied         0.863469
4    Disappointed         0.017553
```